# PowerShell - How to click a button in a website

Tags: powershell

Good evening everyone, need your help. Trying to use PowerShell to click a button on a website but I am getting an "You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression" error

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PrU7I.png)

Here is my code

```
start chrome "url"
```

$submitButton=$ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("number") | Where-Object {$_.innerhtml -eq 'number'}
$submitButton.click();

and here is the button I am trying to click, found by using Chrome developer tools.

[button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6vtUC.png)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

Can be multiple things, the site might have frames or site security that stops bot behavior.

Use Fiddler, you can detect that when clicking the button on their site, then extract that URL and just run an Invoke-WebRequest to get a true value.